# Using package "dplyr" to merge files creates multiple extra rows not in the original CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

```
library("dplyr")
library("readr")
library("tree")

setwd("/Users/yingxiang/Documents/datamining/final proj")

playerStats <- list.files(path='/Users/yingxiang/Documents/datamining/final proj') %>%
  lapply(read_csv) %>%
  bind_rows
```

This is the code that I am using to combine 5 different csv files into one. When I run it, it adds many extra rows not in the original CSV files. In the first column, it is labeled as "library("dplyr") #Load dplyr package". After that it looks like it is adding every other line of code that I have. What can I do to make it so that when I combine the CSV files that it will only use rows/columns from the CSV file.

[this is the csv output that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvj1t.png)

Comment: The files you want to merge hav the same estructure?

Comment: Yes, they all share the exact same names for the columns.

Comment: And the folder hav only csv files? I

Comment: Yes it only has the csv files and the r file that I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
files <- list.files(path='/Users/yingxiang/Documents/datamining/final proj')

    playerStats <-  lapply(files, read.csv)
    playerStats <- do.call(rbind, playerStats)
```